# Will empty value in array consumes space

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, laravel

I am retrieving a table from laravel and storing as temporary array in angular.

for example if returned data is

```
[ {"user_id":1, "usernname":"name1", "email":"email1", "dob":"yy-mm-dd"},
  {"user_id":6, "usernname":"name6", "email":"email6", "dob":"yy-mm-dd"},
  {"user_id":10, "usernname":"name10", "email":"email10", "dob":"yy-mm-dd"} ]
```

I am stroing array as `[1:"name1", 6:"name6", 10:"name10"]`
now if i check for length of that array it gives 11.

will this size *'11'* reflects in my apps performance if i have many no of records?

What I am trying to acheive is

If I am referencing the *'username'* to update values I will rightaway have its index in the temp array rather than checking for its id in the whole rows again and again.

or is there a better-way to do this?

Comment: js doesn't really allow for "sparse" arrays. either they'll be treated as objects which happens to use numeric keys for its contents, or the array will be filled with any "missing" intermediate keys.

Comment: Well of course it will eventually reflect on your apps performance,  but at what number? Make a test case. Then check it.

Comment: Are you looking for `array_filter($array)`?

Comment: Thank you Guys. I thought of re-odering index of the database, but that is not an good idea if I have Foreign keys set.